# A deadlock caused by the duplicate-key error, "X insert intention waiting ... X locks rec but not gap" vs "S locks rec but not gap waiting"

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

I am debugging a deadlock caused by the duplicate-key error. According to [MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html),

> If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index
> record is set. This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should
> there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another
> session already has an exclusive lock. This can occur if another
> session deletes the row.

The example it gives is easy to understand because it involves 3 sessions. But my case just involves 2 transactions. According to the logs, the following deadlock happened, *transaction A* **holds** the lock `lock_mode X locks rec but not gap` and **waiting** `lock_mode X insert intention waiting` while *transaction B* **waiting** `lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting`

And before the deadlock happened we found one of the transactions already inserted into a record, then another transaction tried to insert the same data. But I still do not figure out why the duplicate-key error caused the deadlock.

Can anyone shed some light on it?

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3802025924, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
...
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1469239 page no 46337 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `emicall_cc_man`.`seat_c_state_record` /* Partition `p4` */ trx id 3802025924 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3802025922, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
...
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1469239 page no 46337 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `emicall_cc_man`.`seat_c_state_record` /* Partition `p4` */ trx id 3802025922 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1469239 page no 46338 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `emicall_cc_man`.`seat_c_state_record` /* Partition `p4` */ trx id 3802025922 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
```

[image: deadlock caused by a duplicate-key error]

Comment: Were there any other DML statements in each transaction before the blocking one?  Were there any `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` ?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (Text, please, not images.)

Comment: The 3rd session that may have deleted the row causing the deadlock will not show as it is not part of the deadlock.